# How To move objects in grid in react when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My app.css where i am initialising the grid

```
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.board{
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(170, 236, 170), rgb(236, 236, 167));
    width: 90vmin;
    height: 92vmin;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}
.player{
    background-color: black;
}
```

here is my app.js

```
 import './App.css';
import './scripts/logic.js';
import Player from './components/Player'
import { useState } from 'react'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
          <div className="board" id="board">
              <Player/>
          </div>
          <button>Move Right</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here what are my expectations from this i have player which is nothing just a div which have a background color is a player form as of now i want once the program start the the player appear in the grid at some fixed location`(as you can see in the css the grid 10,10)` and have some buttons screen buttons by which i can move the player in desired location i do  my own research first i try to it with vanila javascript there was a snake game code when i run that with my requirements my tab hangs this happens because of  the a lot of rendering it was happening by animation rendering then i read some more there i get to learn i can assign their position but that gives the issue even if you assign the page not re render than i thought to choose react because it gives me some useful hooks but i cant use my normal vanila javascript code here

[image]

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Would you mind adding punctuation marks and proper capitalization?

Comment: I have updated the question i belive that is explanatery i just want the red block to move when click on move right but want the block to move according to grid cordinates not using margin or padding